# Can I use a different certificate for every AWS ELB, for the same domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have my AWS infrastructure in one account and I want to create a replica of it in another AWS account.
I want the ELB in the second account to have a completely different certificate (for the HTTPS listener) from the one in the first account.

The certificate in the 1st account was uploaded from someone else (I do not know how it was created) but the one I am going to use I want to be created via AWS ACM.

Following the guide, I should add a domain name [*.example.com and example.com] .

Would that create any problems with the current certificate ?

Can I use a different certificate for every ELB, for the same domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have separate certificates created by the ACM service to each secure port.

After creating (and verifying) your domains in ACM, just assign the same certificate to your load balancers. So, for eg., you own `domain1.com` and `domain2.net`. Hence, you can assign each of the following certificates to separate load balancers:

- domain1.com
- domain2.net
- domain1.com AND domain2.net
- domain1.com AND `*.domain1.com`
- domain2.net AND `*.domain2.net`
- domain1.com AND domain2.net AND `*.domain1.com` AND `*.domain2.net`
- Any other combinations thereof

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but your questions seem like you build up or set up the first account by a freelancer and after understanding, you are now doing the same thing with another account and then you will delete the old account.

Let me tell you without any confusion, you can sign your CA certificate more than one authorities you work will not create any issue, your CA authorities must be valid. You do not need to worry your SSL verification will work with the complete same domain name. Kostas Demiris.